# Change path in asset-manifest.json

Tags: reactjs, azure

I've grabbed this example ReactJS project > https://github.com/alik0211/pokedex to experiment with Azure devops. When I build the project locally and use `npm start` in the build folder the app works fine. This is the path for a file http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js`.

But on my Azure environment http://pokedeks.azurewebsites.net/ the server is looking for http://pokedeks.azurewebsites.net/pokedex/static/js/2.c662eb5c.chunk.js. Notice that the `/pokedex/ folder has been added to the path. I'm unsure why this is happening.

I can reproduce it locally by running `serve` in the build folder instead of `npm start`: http://localhost:5000/pokedex/static/js/2.a7ba4e0c.chunk.js

I've tried adding `npm start` to my tasks in the release pipeline but that's also causing errors. So I think the fastest way is to figure out why when using `serve` the `/pokedex/` folder gets added to the routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by replacing the `homepage` value in my `package.json` from `"homepage": "https://alik0211.github.io/pokedex/",` to `"homepage": "./",` now when I run `serve` the paths to the files are correct.